# CSS-Grid: grid-template-rows auto with different results in Safari, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a responsive Square (in grey) with dynamic Content, where an Image (yellow) is to be scaled depending on the length of the text / height of the content div below the Image (blue). While this works perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox come up with two very different outputs as shown below. The don't seem to scale the Image correctly or ignore the auto height of the grid-row and place the content outside of the Square-Div.

What am I missing here?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 25%;
}

.square {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "cover" 
   "content";
  background: grey;
}

.cover {
  grid-area: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='square'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cover'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/I9UFWodl.png' class='image'></div>
      <div class='content'>Dynamic Text<br>Even more Dynamic Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshots**

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9cJ3.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvO4e.png)

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrAd3.png)

I tried this on OSX, all Browsers are current Versions.

Already found one solution, which is using the the Image as background-image for .cover, but unfortunately I need to have an inline image (to apply a shadow and such...), so any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/rx2347/pen/oNNqvNV

Just noticed: This works perfectly fine, if the size of the square becomes larger than the given image. It will scale up the image and remain the proportions of the square, but it won't scale down and do the same thing...

Another observation: Safari does seem to ignore the auto value for grid-template-rows and scales the grid-container up if content exceeds the grid. While Chrome and Firefox stick to a 400x400px square and apply some kind of overflow:hidden to the auto row, Safari scales this up to 800px. Even with overflow:hidden for the .cover container...

```css
.grid {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  display: grid;
  background:grey;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas: "cover"
                       "info";
  overflow:hidden;
}

.cover {
  grid-area:cover;
  border:5px solid green;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
  background:red;
  height:800px;
}

.info {
  grid-area:info;
  color:white;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='cover'>
    <div class='content'>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class='info'>text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u plz send the image cover.png image or add this codepen? Need to check the image..

Comment: sure, its at [link](https://i.imgur.com/I9UFWodl.png) - dimensions are 200x320px, but this shouldn't matter at all in the solution I am looking for, as the image sizes will be different in every container @Manikandan2811

Comment: ok i will check and let u know!! 10mins

Comment: btw: this might very well be a mistake with the height:100% for the image, i am aware that safari handles that different, thats why i added the .cover wrapper... but with no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Do u want to cover the yellow image full of grey box?

Comment: nope. it should scale to the remaining space in the .square depending on the height of the .content div, hence the grid-template-rows: auto fit-content. which works just as it should in chrome... i could do this with javascript and some math, but thats not really an elegant solution as you have to recalc after every window resize.

Comment: but in ly local its look same in all browsers.. do u have a codepen or fiddle?

Comment: added codepen: https://codepen.io/rx2347/pen/oNNqvNV

Comment: still its working fine for me.. it may be have to check ur browser version?

Comment: try resizing it, so the .square is smaller than 320px in width/height. thats were the problem kicks in.

Comment: I resized my browser. the grey box adjusted automatically, but the image not adjusted.. Is this the issue?

Comment: all the content should be in the square at any given size of the square. and while it is working scaling up, its not scaling down the image when the square height becomes smaller than the image height at 320px. which is really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding another .container and overflow:hidden to the .cover div.

Not sure, why this has to be added for Safari to fit all the divs inside the square though as there actually is no overflow.

**Anyways. Use overflow:hidden for Safari when using grid-template-rows: auto min-content; for the auto row.**

```css
  html,body {
    height:100%;
  }

  .wrapper {
    width:50%;
  }

  .square {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background:green;
  }

  .container {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

  .grid {
    display:grid;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
      "cover"
      "content";
    background:grey;
  }

  .cover {
    grid-area:cover;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .image {
    max-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
  }

  .content {
    grid-area:content;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
  }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

<div class='square'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cover'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/I9UFWodl.png' class='image'></div>
      <div class='content'>Dynamic Content<br>Can even be multiple lines and the content will stay within the Square</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: can confirm, grid children with height:100% break on safari given its 'strict' implementation and lack of a defined height on parent, but, wrapping your grid with a display:block+overflow:hidden; magically makes it work, even if there is no height defined.